# How can I format a VeraCrypt partition with ExtFS from MacOS?

Tags: filesystems, veracrypt

I want to move my TrueCrypt partition to VeraCrypt. It is currently formatted with NTFS and because I switched to MacOS (for now) I want to move to ExtFS.

How can I format a VeraCrypt partition with ExtFS? I already [read](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/103640/veracrypt-create-encrypted-container-volume-format-options-filesystem-none) that this should be possible, the question is how? Just formatting without an FS and later formatting is not possible - I get an error mounting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ExFAT support has added to Windows and Linux in the latest 1.17-BETA
>   (Build 18) [of VeraCrypt].
>
> For MacOSX, no external command or OS function could be found that
>   would enable VeraCrypt to create exFAT volumes. This explains why
>   exFAT support was not added of MacOSX (no exFAT source code is
>   included in VeraCrypt and we rely only on OS capability in order to
>   avoid any possible patent or license issue).
>
> If someone does now an OSX command that can be used to create exFAT
>   disk, please come forward.

(From: idrassi, In: https://veracrypt.codeplex.com/discussions/650401)